# Integral of products of two modified Bessel function of second kind and power

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

I would like to calculate the closed-form expression for the following integral:
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty x^{a} K_0(b\sqrt{x}) K_\nu(c\sqrt{x}) dx,
\end{align}
where $a,b,c$ and $\nu$ are all positive constants.
Note that $K_{\mu}(\cdot)$ is the modified Bessel function of second kind (also called the Macdonald function).

Comment: I have worked out this integration with Mathematica. But the result seems strange that it contains the ratio of two infinity parameters (i.e., $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$).

Are there any references to solve this?

Comment: Applying [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3104763) gives
$$4^a b^{-2 a - 2} G_{2, 2}^{2, 2} {\left( \left( \frac c b \right)^2 \middle |
 {-a, -a \atop -\frac \nu 2, \frac \nu 2} \right)},$$
which can be expanded into a sum of two ${_2 F_1}$ functions by Slater's theorem. The integral converges for $\nu < 2 a + 2$.

Comment: @Maxim Thank you very much!