# Special function expression for the (truncated) moment of the generalized Gamma distribution

Tags: improper-integrals, special-functions, gamma-function

The, kind of, truncated moment of the [generalized Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_gamma_distribution) for positive $a,d$ and $p$ is
$$\int_0^\infty (x-k)_+^a x^{d-1}e^{-x^p}dx=\frac1p\int_0^\infty (y^{\frac1p}-k)_+^a\,y^{\frac dp-1}e^{-y}\,dy. \tag1$$
The truncated moment of the Gamma distribution can be [transformed into the confluent hypergeometric function of the second kind](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3703382/64809) defined as [such](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheSecondKind.html). Is there a similar special function transform for integral $(1)$?

Comment: There is a closed form in terms of the Fox H-function,
$$\int_k^\infty x^{d - 1} (x - k)^a e^{-x^p} dx =
k^{a + d} \hspace {1.5px} \Gamma(a + 1) H_{1, 2}^{2, 0} {\left(
 k^p \middle| {(1 - d, p) \atop (0, 1), (-a - d, p)} \right)}, \\
k > 0, \; p > 0, \; \operatorname {Re} a > -1.$$

Comment: @Maxim: Could you please give a detailed derivation as an answer?

Comment: It's an application of [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3104763). We need
$$\mathcal M[x \mapsto e^{-x}](s) = \Gamma(s), \\
\mathcal M[x \mapsto (x - k)_+^a](s) =
\frac {k^{s + a} \Gamma(a + 1) \Gamma(-a - s)} {\Gamma(1 - s)}.$$