# Integration, confluent hypergeometric functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

I am currently struggling to find out how we arrive at the following equation: $\int\limits_{s/2}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha^{2m-1}e^{-m\alpha^2}}{\sqrt{4\alpha^2-s^2}}d\alpha= \frac{\pi \sec (m\pi)}{4}\left\lbrace \frac{2^{1-2m} \sqrt{\pi}s^{2m-1} {}_1\mathcal{M}_1\left(m,\frac{1}{2}+m,\frac{-ms^2}{4} \right) }{\Gamma(1-m)} -m^{\frac{1}{2}-m}{}_1\mathcal{M}_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}-m,\frac{-ms^2}{4} \right) \right\rbrace$, where ${}_1\mathcal{M}_1(a,b,z)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(b-a)\Gamma(a)}\int\limits_0^1e^{z\alpha}\alpha^{a-1}(1-\alpha)^{b-a-1}d\alpha$ is the regularized confluent hypergeometric function.

Actually I needed to evaluate the above integral for my research work and hence, I evaluated it using Mathematica. The result works perfectly fine for me. But now I want to know (at least the intuition behind it) how did Mathematica obtain this solution. I have been thinking over this for quite some time now, but unfortunately haven't succeeded yet.

What I have been able to obtain after some manipulations is the following: $\int\limits_{s/2}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha^{2m-1}e^{-m\alpha^2}}{\sqrt{4\alpha^2-s^2}}d\alpha=\frac{1}{4}(\frac{s}{2})^{2m-1}\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}(\sec \theta)^{2m}e^{-\frac{ms^2}{4}\sec^2\theta}d\theta$. Even giving this as the input, Mathematica gives the same result as above. But again, I cannot understand...how.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: If there are no assumptions on $m$ except $m \geq 0$, you can use the general formula for the integral of a product of two Meijer G-functions.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: It's [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3104763). Let $x = 4 \alpha^2/s^2$. The Mellin transforms are
$$\mathcal M[x \mapsto (x - 1)^{-1/2} H(x - 1)](s) =
\frac {\sqrt \pi \, \Gamma(1/2 - s)} {\Gamma(1 - s)}, \\
\mathcal M[x \mapsto e^{-x}](s) = \Gamma(s),$$
so the integral is
$$\frac {\sqrt \pi} 4 \left( \frac s 2 \right)^{2 m - 1}
 G_{1, 2}^{2, 0} {\left( \frac {m s^2} 4 \middle|
  {1 - m \atop 0, \frac 1 2 - m} \right)}.$$
Then apply [Slater's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G#Relationship_between_the_G-function_and_the_generalized_hypergeometric_function).

Comment: Thank you very much!