# Why does the integral $\int_{x = 0}^{x = \infty } {\frac{{\sqrt{ax}{K_1}\left( {\sqrt {ax} } \right)}}{{x + 1}}} dx$ result in the Meijer G function?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

By using Mathematica, I am able to obtain the result of $\int_{x = 0}^{x = \infty } {\frac{{\sqrt {ax} {K_1}\left( {\sqrt {ax} } \right)}}{{x + 1}}} dx$ where $a>0$ as [image]

But I am not sure why does the Meijer G function pops up.

Could you kindly explain the reason for this ?

Thank you !

Comment: Essentially it's the [convolution theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3104763) for the Mellin transform. The Mellin transforms of the factors are
$$\mathcal M[x \mapsto (x + 1)^{-1}](s) =
\Gamma(s) \Gamma(1 - s), \\
\mathcal M[x \mapsto K_1(\sqrt {a x})](s) =
(a/4)^{-s} \Gamma(1/2 + s) \Gamma(-1/2 + s)/2.$$

Comment: Could you elaborate more, I still do not understand the relation between the Meilin transform and the appearance of the Meijer G function ?