# Definite integral in terms of special functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

I'm working in asymptotic expansions and it appear this integral

$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^{2m}}t^n(t-a)^{s}dt,\quad a\in\mathbb{R}$$

where $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $s\in(-1,0]$.

When $a=0$, it becomes a Gamma function. I wonder if it can be written in terms of some special function when $a\neq0$.

Any help will be welcomed.

Comment: Use `\quad` or `\qquad` for spacing, instead of so many `\,`s.  FYI, `\,` is a thin space, `\ ` is a space, `\;` is a tad thicker of a space.  But for sizeable spacing, use `\quad` or `\qquad`.  Try it in practice.  (I used `\quad` to edit your post above.)

Comment: There is a closed form in terms of the Meijer G-function. But if the question is about asymptotics, finding a closed form may be unnecessary.

Comment: Dear Maxim, can you write or say something about this closed form in terms of the Meijer G-function?

Comment: It's [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3104763). The Mellin transforms are
$$F(p) = \mathcal M[t \mapsto e^{-t^{2 m}}](p) =
\frac 1 {2 m} \Gamma {\left( \frac p {2 m} \right)}, \\
G(p) = \mathcal M[t \mapsto (t + 1)^s](p) =
\frac 1 {\Gamma(-s)} \Gamma(p) \Gamma(-p - s),$$
so for $a < 0$ we get
$$\mathcal M[t \mapsto e^{-t^{2 m}} (t - a)^s](n + 1) =
(-a)^s \mathcal M^{-1}[p \mapsto F(n + 1 - p) G(p)]
 {\left( -\frac 1 a \right)}.$$
The Fox H-function can be converted to a G-function by applying the multiplication theorem to $\Gamma(2 m (p + p_0))$.